# My muslim husband divorced me saying 3 times 'i divorce you' Can he take me back?

Tags: talaq

I am not a Muslim, but Christian. I married a man in Gulf [Ibadi sekt] - there was wedding and nikkah without any paper contract. I did leave him few weeks after that marriage despite loving him. I had really valid reason to run away. Since 4 months I am back to Europe and we didn't meet, and last days in [minor] anger he wrote to me 'I divorce you' 3 times. Then he said we are not divorced, that he will fix it etc. As for me, this divorce is valid, I read about it online. I assumed that this is my destiny and that's better for me and decided to avoid contacting him. 
Is there any way for him to take me back? Some say till the iddah ends, he can take me back. Some, that after pronouncing this 3 times, there is no such possibilities. Take into account his sekt and culture [gulf ibadi]. Honestly speaking I don't want it anymore, but I respect the rules of the marriage, since I did it out of my heart and consciously. I fear that he will come after some months and say 'I am taking you back'. Please, explain me, since all I've read online seems confusing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because talaq/divorce issues need a fatwa, we are not a fatwa site.

Comment: Please note that in most sects talaq doesn't happen if one is angry, but to properly clear out whether this is the case or not you or in first place your "husband" needs to consult a scholar.

Comment: Yes he said he will contact me saying it is not a divorce despite saying this 3 times, then he remains silent. I want to make plans in my life that is why I need to know when I can really feel 'free'. I am on a side of a person who doesn't have any Muslims around, my only one source of knowledge is internet. I am afraid that after some months I will get information that I am married. Please understand me.

Comment: I do understand you the problem is the Ibadi sect is a minority under Muslims of roughly 2.72 million Ibadis worldwide, which means much less than 2% of all Muslims are Ibadi and their practices are hardly known by non-Ibadis!

Comment: We get a few triple talaq questions https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/17163

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because divorce issues need a fatwa, we are not a fatwa site. Consult an Islamic court or Mufti to settle your issues.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit tricky because the marriage was not registered anywhere I believe but if we were to assume that it did happen in front of witnesses and the husband initiated the divorce then if there is no reconciliation during the waiting period, the divorce will be final. It doesn't matter if the husband or for that matter the wife wants a one-sided reconciliation, both parties must agree to it. Hence, if you are not interested in the marriage anymore then wait out the prescribed period and that is that.